# Unable to set default value for set_fact in Ansible

Tags: variables, split, ansible, default

Lets consider the user passes a Number parameter to my ansible-playbook as

```
ansible-playbook /app/test.yml 
-e  "Number=22235_ReDep_292001105550"
```

I want set_fact "Number_New" to be the string before the first underscore "_" i.e 22235 and "Status" to be everything after the first underscore "_" i.e

```
Expectation:
Number_New should be "22235"
Status should be "ReDep_292001105550"
```

Second scenario; the user may pass -e "Number=22235". This this case i want the set_fact "Number_New" should be same as the "Number=22235" passed while the Status should be "%" modulus symbol.

```
Expectation:
Number_New should be "22235"
Status should be "%"
```

Below is my playbook attempt which works fine when parameter passed is "Number=22235_ReDep_292001105550" but fails when -e "Number=22235"

```
  tasks:
   - name: Populate number and status from user input
     set_fact:
       Number_New: "{{ Number.split('_')[0] | default(Number) }}"
       Status: "{{ Number.split('_')[1] }}_{{ Number.split('_')[2] | default('%') }}"
```

Error when it fails:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 1\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/test.yml': line 32, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - name: Populate number and status from user input\n     ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: `Number.split('_')[1]` does not exists with your second input data. You would need to default it as well as `Number.split('_')[2]` then test on the constructed string and replace it if it only contains `_` with your final default value. There are ansible only ways to do this but it becomes overly complicated and hard to read (when you get back to your code 3 month later....). It would probably be easier to develop a [custom filter](https://opensolitude.com/2016/05/21/ansible-jinja2-filter-plugins.html) in this case, or to review the way you pass your parameters to the playbook.

Answer (score 0):

The task below does the job

```
    - set_fact:
        Number_New: "{{ nsplit.0 }}"
        Status: "{{ nsplit.1|default('%') }}"
      vars:
        nsplit: "{{ Number.split('_', 1) }}"
```